# How to draw checkbox onto message box in hook procedure?

Tags: c, winapi, messagebox

I am making a custom message box in Win32 api. So, I created the hook procedure and things, following the tutorial from [here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-messagebox).

*I successfully changed the button text, but, when I draw a checkbox onto the message box, and I press one of the messagebox buttons, the checkbox gets drawn onto the main window!*

**My code:**

```
typedef void (*mbxdraw)(HWND);
static HHOOK hMsgHk;        // internal linkage; local to this file
static mbxdraw drawproc;    // internal linkage

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    HWND hwndMsgbx;
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hMsgHk, nCode, wp, lp);
    switch (nCode) {
    case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        // obtain the message box handle
        hwndMsgbx = (HWND) wp;
        drawproc(hwndMsgbx);    // calls function pointer
        return 0;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMsgHk, nCode, wp, lp);
}

int msgbox(HWND hOwner, char *text, char *cap, UINT flags, mbxdraw md)
{
    int ret;

    hMsgHk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    drawproc = md;

    ret = MessageBox(hOwner, text, cap, flags);

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMsgHk);
    return ret;
}
```

**In the function that I pass (main.cpp):**

```
void draw(HWND hMsg)
{
    // this is the checkbox: 
    CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Check", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX,
                 10, 70, 65, 10, hMsg, (HMENU) CHKID, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hMsg, IDYES), "Save Changes");
}
```

The checkbox gets drawn onto the main window as soon as I press one of the two buttons on the message box. It even gets drawn with the same exact X- and Y- coordinates, and the same width, and height and text.

I thought maybe I was obtaining the message box handle the wrong way, but I saw that the address of the message box handle was not equal to the handle of the main window.

The reason I am passing the function pointer rather than just writing the code,  is because later, when this will actually work, I will put this in a c++ wrapper class.

Comment: Why don't you make a dialog?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i want the messagebox to look native

Comment: Are you prepared for your app to crash on as yet unreleased versions of Windows?

Comment: How could this crash? @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Because you are hacking at a dialog that might be implemented totally differently in a future version. You do realise that you are expected **not** to do what you are doing right?

Comment: You will have difficulty finding a position on the dialog that is guaranteed to be safe to inject your checkbox. The layout of the dialog has changed over time, and it is likely to change again in the future. It may even be updated so it doesn't use HWNDs any more (like task dialogs).

Comment: When hacking `MessageBox()` like this, it is not uncommon to resize the dialog to make space for custom controls, so they don't interfere with the dialog's native controls. But, on Vista and later, you really should use `TaskDialogIndirect()` instead to display a message box with a native verification checkbox on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I test it in this simple program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

#define CHKID 100

typedef void (*mbxdraw)(HWND);
static HHOOK hMsgHk;        // internal linkage; local to this file
static mbxdraw drawproc;    // internal linkage

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    HWND hwndMsgbx;
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hMsgHk, nCode, wp, lp);
    switch (nCode) {
    case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        // obtain the message box handle
        hwndMsgbx = (HWND) wp;
        drawproc(hwndMsgbx);    // calls function pointer
        return 0;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMsgHk, nCode, wp, lp);
}

void draw(HWND hMsg)
{
    // this is the checkbox: 
    CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Check", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX,
                 10, 70, 65, 10, hMsg, (HMENU) CHKID, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hMsg, IDYES), "Save Changes");
}

int msgbox(HWND hOwner, char *text, char *cap, UINT flags, mbxdraw md)
{
    int ret;

    hMsgHk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    drawproc = md;

    ret = MessageBox(hOwner, text, cap, flags);

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMsgHk);
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    msgbox(NULL, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The brown fox", MB_YESNO, draw);
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe you create some other window in the same thread before to remove the hook?

Answer (score 2):

Your code embodies the wrong approach. You want to make a native message dialog with a check box. The `TaskDialogIndirect` is provided for that purpose.

Your approach, even if you fix it, it not robust to changes in implementation in future Windows releases. Use the system provided API.